# How do you concatenate two files of arrays into one with jq?

Tags: arrays, json, file, concatenation, jq

Suppose file one:

```
[1, 1, 2]
```

and file two:

```
[2, 3, 3]
```

How do I concatenate the arrays in the two files, otherwise leaving the contents alone?  That is, output of

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

P.S. I want to concatenate arrays of objects, not just ints, if that makes a difference.

I tried

`cat one two | jq`

but that just puts them next to each other:  `[1, 1, 2] [2, 3, 3]`

Comment: Did you try `jq -s 'add' one two any`?

Comment: @Inian That works. If you submit it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

jq is quite flexible. Here's a solution without slurping:

```
jq -n '[inputs[]]' a1 a2
```